# union on tables with the different number of columns in scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to perform a UNIONAll between two tables that have a different number of columns.

samples of data

| Movieid | features | probability |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 0.37986 | 0.50231 |
| 4 | 0.83521 | 0.2925 |
| 6 | 0.9925 | 0.7062 |
| 8 | 0.327 | 0.764 |

| Movieid | title | genres |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Toy Story (1995) | Adventure,Animation,children |
| 2 | Jumanji (1995) | Children |
| 3 | Waiting to Exhale (1995) | comedy,Drama,Romance |
| 4 | Father of the Bride Part II (1995) | comedy |
| 5 | Sabrina (1995) | Romance,comedy |

root:

File1

```
   |-- MovieIdId: integer (nullable = false)
   |-- features: Double (nullable = false)
   |-- probability: Double (nullable = false)
```

File2

```
   |--MovieId: integer (nullable = false)
   |--title: String (nullable = false)
   |-- genres: String (nullable = false)
```

code:`

```
`val Data = sc.textFile("file:///usr/local/File1").map(_.split(",")).map(p => DataClass(p(0).trim.toInt, p(1).trim, p(2).trim)).toDF()
Data.registerTempTable("Genres")
val Data2 = sc.textFile("file:///usr/local/File2").map(_.split(",")).map(p =>Movie(p(0).trim.toInt, p(1).trim, p(1).trim)).toDF()
Data.registerTempTable("Tags")
val df=sqlContext.sql("SELECT MovieId, title, genres FROM Genres UNION ALL SELECT MovieId, features, probability FROM Tags")
```

**Update:**

I want to make table which contains MovieId,features,probability,genres.

How to merge two columns from two tables without duplicate?

Comment: are you sure you want to unionAll and not a join ?

Comment: sorry,I'm new in spark.I try only unionAll.

Comment: can you add your input dataframe and your desired output ?

Comment: I update my question with input.

Comment: i wanted input exemple DATA and output exemple DATA and not schema.

Comment: I update question with data.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want a full outer join not union:

```
val df = Data.join(Data2, Seq("Movieid"), "full")

df.show
//+-------+--------+-----------+----------------------------------+----------------------------+
//|Movieid|features|probability|title                             |genres                      |
//+-------+--------+-----------+----------------------------------+----------------------------+
//|1      |null    |null       |Toy Story (1995)                  |Adventure,Animation,children|
//|6      |0.9925  |0.7062     |null                              |null                        |
//|3      |null    |null       |Waiting to Exhale (1995)          |comedy,Drama,Romance        |
//|5      |null    |null       |Sabrina (1995)                    |Romance,comedy              |
//|4      |0.83521 |0.2925     |Father of the Bride Part II (1995)|comedy                      |
//|8      |0.327   |0.764      |null                              |null                        |
//|2      |0.37986 |0.50231    |Jumanji (1995)                    |Children                    |
//+-------+--------+-----------+----------------------------------+----------------------------+
```

Or using SQL:

```
val df = spark.sql("""
  select *
  from Genres g
  full outer join Tags t
  on g.Movieid = t.Movieid
""")
```